# How to insert video (mp4) via file browser in CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

How to insert video (mp4 as html5) via file browser in CKEditor?

CKEditor [don't have 'Video' button](http://ckeditor.com/demo#full) on toolbar in full configuration.